# Security: git server with ssh authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, security, unix

1. I created user 'git-server'
2. Installed `openssh-server`
3. Modified `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` added `PasswordAuthentication no`
4. Added to `.ssh/authorized_keys` public case of my colleagues

**Questions:**

- Is 'git-server' user secure for my system? What is the worst scenario for system if malefactor gets access to 'git-server', providing the fact 'git-server' is `sudoer`
- How can I forbid to 'git-server' all operations apart `git` commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change default shell of user git-server to git-shell.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell.html

> This is a login shell for SSH accounts to provide restricted Git access. It permits execution only of server-side Git commands implementing the pull/push functionality, plus custom commands present in a subdirectory named git-shell-commands in the user’s home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets look at how you set up that git-server account on the system.

> Modified /etc/ssh/sshd_config added PasswordAuthentication no

because you set password authentication to no, then trying to log into the system under that name remotely is virtually impossible without a valid SSH key. As far as I am aware, I don't think ssh keys have been cracked granted it does depend on the cipher and cipher complexity you are using to determine that.

So now that fact is out of the way, if someone managed to get access to that account. It would most likely mean, someone who already had access to your system that was given privileges to use su would have done it, or somehow if you locked down your system properly, someone gained access to root which is more impossible than gaining access to the git-server account. But if that isn't the case and they did log into that account remotely using SSH, then everyone using SSH is in trouble as that would mean anyones system that uses ssh would be vulnerable. Now the most damage that can be done is the same amount of damage you can cause with your normal account with sudo privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Some variables to set if there's any need to follow along with suggestions...

```
_git_user='git-user'
_git_group='git-devs'
_git_home_base="/srv/${_git_group}"
_client_certs_root='/home/admin/client-certs'
```

... which'll be written from the perspective of your server admin account.

---

> > 1. I created user 'git-server'

By chance did ya lock it and make it a system account?

```
sudo adduser\
 --system\
 --disabled-password\
 --gecos ''\
 --shell "$(which git-shell)"\
 --home "${_git_home_base,,}/${_git_user,,}"\
 --ingroup "${_git_group}"\
 "${_git_user}"
```

> ---
>
> Note, if `$(which git-shell)` resolves to a file path but `--shell` option pops errors then...

```
if [ -e "$(which git-shell)" ] && ! grep -q -- "$(which git-shell)" /etc/shells; then
    sudo tee -a /etc/shells 1>/dev/null <<<"$(which git-shell)"
fi
```

> ... may be helpful in appending the `git-shell` path to the `/etc/shells` file
>
> ---

---

> > 2. Installed `openssh-server`
> > 3. Modified `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` added `PasswordAuthentication no`

Have you disabled **`root`** password authentication over SSH?

**`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`** bits that may be helpfull...

```
permitrootlogin without-password


## Additionally consider locking-down other unneeded features
Match Group git-devs
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  AllowStreamLocalForwarding no
  PermitOpen none
```

---

> > 4. Added to `.ssh/authorized_keys` public case of my colleagues

Where precisely did you add their public keys?

Here's some example commands for setting up three Git accounts...

```
declare -a _accounts_keys=(
    ["name-one"]="${_client_certs_root}/${_git_group}/name-one/ssh.pub"
    ["name-two"]="${_client_certs_root}/${_git_group}/name-two/ssh.pub"
    ["name-three"]="${_client_certs_root}/${_git_group}/name-three/ssh.pub"
)



for _name in "${!_accounts_keys[@]}"; do
    sudo su --login "${_name}" --shell /bin/bash <<EOF
mkdir .ssh
tee -a .ssh/authorized_keys 1>/dev/null <<<"$(<"${_accounts_keys[${_name}]}")"
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
EOF
done
```

---

> > Is 'git-server' user secure for my system? What is the worst scenario for system if malefactor gets access to 'git-server', providing the fact 'git-server' is `sudoer`

No and if you've added everyone's keys to the same account, and that account is a `sudoer`, then the amount of *nightmare fuel* I could douse this situation with is near limitless...

---

> > How can I forbid to 'git-server' all operations apart git commands?

Add `git-shell-commands/no-interactive-login` script to each Git account...

```
for _name in "${!_accounts_keys[@]}"; do
    sudo su --login "${_name}" --shell /bin/bash <<EOC
tee 'git-shell-commands/no-interactive-login' 1>/dev/null <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash
printf 'Hi %s, you have successfully authenticated!\n' "${USER}"
printf 'However, there is not an interactive shell here.\n'
exit 128
EOF

chmod u+x 'git-shell-commands/no-interactive-login'
EOC
done
```

... so long as there are no other executable files within the `git-shell-command` directory the account will be limited to non-interactive git commands; provided that the account's shell is also set correctly.

---

The above isn't the most secure but balanced with convenience;

- `git-devs` group should be different for each account if the cross cloning is not wanted, eg `name-one` could (when the primary group is shared between accounts), `git clone name-two@server:/srv/git-devs/name-two/project-name` if they knew how things where structured server side.

> Note, if permissions where `600` this could be disabled per-project within an individual account, and if permissions where `660` that would enable the shared group to `push` as well as `pull` to a repository... personally I find `640` to be the *best* of both options as this allows a group to share code among one another without to much fear of a stray `git push -f` from another account messing things up.

- For examples on other `git-shell-commands` scripts consider checking the [`git-utilities/git-shell-commands`](https://github.com/git-utilities/git-shell-commands) repository, where the above tips where adapted from, though that would *tip* things even more towards convenience.

> In short **don't** add the above linked scripts if ya cannot trust clients to not try and *pop-ah-shell* because such things are designed so that the *need* for an interactive shell isn't as prevalent.

**Bonus points**

- check out `man --pager='less -p "ChrootDirectory"' sshd_config` for hints on what can be done to further secure the SSH server
- check `man git-shell` and `man git-daemon` for related documentation; there be some useful options for both locking things down and/or making the server a little easier to communicate with, eg. `--strict-paths`, `--base-path=<path>`, and `--listen=<host_or_ipaddr>` might be worth looking into further

---

If there's something questionable about the above consider commenting so that this answer may be improved.